# How to refactor this symfony code?

Tags: forms, symfony1, action

In action.class.php:

```
$form = new NewsForm();
$form->setWidget('thumbnail', new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $news['images'])));
$form->getWidget('summarize')->setDefault($news['summarize']);
$form->getWidget('title')->setDefault($news['title']);
```

Where `$news` is generated in previous steps;

It looks redundant,how to refactor it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your code is not redunant until you use the same code in mutliple actions.
To make it reusable, you can make use of the `options` parameter in the the [form constructor](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm#method___construct) and change the form as follows:

```
class NewsForm extends ... {

    public function configure() {
        //Whatever you do here
        //....

        // if a news is set we configure certain fields
        if($news = $this->getOption('news', false)) {
            $this->setWidget('thumbnail', new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $news['images'])));
            $this->setDefault('summarize', $news['summarize']);
            $this->setDefault('title', $news['title']);
        }
    }
}
```

The you can create the form with:

```
$form = new NewsForm(array(), array('news' => $news));
```

Reference: [`sfForm - getOption`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm#method_getoption)